# SSH is looking in the wrong place for the public/private key pair on Windows

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I'm trying to configure GIT on my Windows XP machine, but SSH keeps creating and looking for the public/private key pair in non-sensical places, e.g. /.ssh/id_rsa

Is there a configuration file in the GIT Installation for Windows where I can switch this to my home directory, or another user defined place? By default, it offers to create new key pairs at //.ssh/id_rsa but that gives me the error "Could not create directory '//.ssh'." And when I'm able to find a directory I can create it in, GIT won't look there.

Comment: The "could not create directory" error can be solved by running `sudo` restarting your shell as administrator. I realize this doesn't solve the root of your problem but thought it's worth mentioning since someone with that problem might end up here

Comment: Windows machine. What SUDO do you expect there?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Figured out how to manually set my home directory in Windows XP:

1. Right click "My Computer"
2. Choose the "Advanced" tab
3. Click the "Environmental Variables" button
4. Under the "System variables" section, click "New"
5. In the "Variable name" enter in "home".
6. In the "Variable value" enter in the path to your profile.

To do the same via command prompt do :

```
setx HOME "your\path\to\home"
```

( Please note the suffix x - This is used to persist the change )

Comment: Just as a tip, I honestly don't remember if this option is available in XP, but at least in newer versions of Windows, you can add this as a user variable instead of a system variable. Obviously the home directory for your user is not a system wide thing.

Comment: This fixed my problem in Windows 10.
I'm running Cygwin git, and it wasn't pulling the ssh-key.

Comment: This still fails.$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Users/myuser                debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

Answer (score 9):

[Recommended](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/111/?page=2) method from MSYS2 is to set `db_home` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to your home directory.

*Credit to [@VarunAgw](https://serverfault.com/users/291620/varunagw) for [pointing](https://serverfault.com/a/707890/290725) in the right direction.*

Git-for-Windows includes `env` in `db_home`, which should read your `HOME` bash variable, however, it is [unreliable](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/736#issuecomment-215123009).

Comment: I found that some software such as Orcad will set `%HOME%=C:\Users\[accountname]\AppData\Roaming\SPB_16.6` or `C:\SPB_data`

But for some reason I don't want to change it.

Then this method of modifying `/etc/nsswitch.conf` really helps.

setup as the following line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` did make ssh-keygen sets default location to `%USERPROFILE%`

`db_home: /%H`

Comment: And here it is 2019 and OrCAD still causes this problem.  I just helped a colleague through this today!

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar problem on Windows 7.  The `HOME` environment variable seemed to be set correctly:

```
$ echo $HOME
C:\Users\craibuc
```

However, attempts to connect to test github's `ssh` access failed:

```
$ ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
Could not create directory 'C/.ssh'.
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (C/.ssh/known_hosts).
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

For some reason, `ssh` was attempting to access `C/.ssh`.

When I set the variable using `setx HOME /c/users/craibuc` and restarted the shell, I was able to connect:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
Hi craibuc! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 5):

Check `which ssh` to see if you are using `/usr/bin/ssh` or something else, that might have installed by accident.

In my case my ssh was replaced by **Chocolatey** after installing `rsync`. After running `choco uninstall rsync`, my SSH was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem when using a machine with domain policy setting the user profile to a network drive (in this case mapped to `Z:`).

When trying to do anything from Powershell I'd get messages like this. Setting `home` PATH variable didn't help.

```
git clone ssh://myusername@mydomain.com:1234/myproject
Cloning into 'myproject'...
Could not create directory '/z/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host '[mydomain.com]:1234 ([1.1.1.1]:1234)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 00:11:22:33:$4:55:66:77:88.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/z/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I cloned from git bash it was fine, as `/z/.ssh` etc is a valid way to point to `Z:\.ssh` from a shell.

Comment: And do you happen to know what you did in order to resolve the issue?

Comment: ...`cloned from git bash`

Comment: i have same issue but neither cmd nor git bash works

Answer (score -1):

`ln -s /c/Users/rofrol/.ssh /home/rofrol/` worked for me.

This did not:

```bash
$ echo $HOME
/c/Users/rofrol

$ cat ~/nsswitch.conf
db_home: /c/Users/rofrol

$ cat /home/rofrol/nsswitch.conf
db_home: /c/Users/rofrol

$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# Begin /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: files db
group: files db

db_enum: cache builtin

#db_home: cygwin desc
db_home: /c/Users/rofrol
db_shell: cygwin desc
db_gecos: cygwin desc

# End /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Probably because of this:

> SSH will require /home/$USER

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/736#issuecomment-215123009

Comment: should be able to change config path rather than link home directory into .ssh

Comment: @TamusJRoyce maybe, I just like to store configs in git for windows, linux and macos. And the same location helps.

Answer (score -3):

On Windows 7 Just Place your Private Key ( id_rsa ) inside C:\Users\.ssh FOLDER
If .ssh Folder doesnt exist just create it.
Download GIT for Windows, cd into your Project Directory and do 
git clone ssh://@/.git

Comment: The issue is actually related to HOME not being set, as the accepted answer points out