# Unable to push master to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm unable to push use git push in github as well as heroku, i have tried various methods as suggested on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github) . pls help to resolve this problem .. i see the following report while i try to push.

```
D:\My\weblog>git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

D:\My\weblog>ssh -v git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.16.232.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debia
n-5pgsql1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5pgsql1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Am using windows 7 .

Comment: erm, you don't have permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end)

Answer (score 17):

type in `gem install heroku`

Then upload rsa key of github to heroku

```
$ heroku keys:add
Uploading ssh public key /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Once you key in configured with heroku and github with command all your code goes to github and from there to Heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

and soon you will see these messages

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
```

Comment: Not sure about `gem ...`, but `heroku keys:add` definitely solved my issue (upvoted).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like heroku isn't accepting your machine's public keys. Be sure that you've given your public key to heroku. [Heroku's guide on SSH keys](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) should help.

Comment: Are you able to SSH to other servers using public keys?

Comment: I am newbie and am unable access github and heroku for now.. i tried to work it on ubuntu but its even worse.. heroku wont even install in ubuntu !!

Comment: Try making a backup of your local keys and restarting the entire key-setup process on Windows. You can also try contacting Heroku's support as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: This link helped me fix the same problem.  I used heroku keys to see I had two keys.  Then I typed heroku remove:keys email@email.com twice to remove them - then used heroku add:keys - and when I tried to push to heroku, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue on OSX with heroku-toolbelt/2.32.8.  Even after following heroku I was unsuccessful until I used a key in the default path - IE ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

Comment: Placing the key in the id_rsa default space was the *only* thing I could do to get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - turns out I forgot that Windows 8 doesn't start the command prompt with admin privileges by default like Windows 7 did.  Running it as administrator fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu `sudo su` solved it for me.

When I used ssh to generate the key, then if you read the contents of "id_rsa.pub" there's a username at the end of the file. For me it was "root@pc-name", but without `sudo su` the current username is "username@pc-name" instead of "root@pc-name". `sudo su` solves that by switching to "root@pc-name".

Comment: This solution worked for me. I suspect that a better practice is to generate a key with the user role rather than use the root one.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows and Cygwin, I had to start Cygwin with admin privileges before it would let me push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I solved it with change cmd command with Git Bash. Do everything on Git.