# GitHub: ssh -T git@github.com -> Permission denied (publickey). [Windows 7]

Tags: windows-7, permissions, github, public-key

I have a problem and didn't find anything on stackoverflow or google.
When i run ssh -T git@github.com I get the error Permission denied (publickey).

The helps in the Git Help guide doesn't help.
Can someone help me?

OK i got the solution, maybe someone needs it so here we go:

Ok, i got it finally.

First of all it is to say I am running here the Windows 7 OS in German 64bit! I don't know if this is important.

Well, in this guide: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ they say, that the files where create in C:/Users/[PC-Name]/.ssh/

So in this folder there shall be the files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. When i looked them up, i wasn't able to find even the folder. So where are the necessary files?

I run the search and i find them in: C:\Users[yourpcname]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\SysWOW64

I don't know why or how they get there. I never typed in this path.
Ok, so now just copy the files and create the .ssh folder in C:/Users/[PC-Name]/ move to the directory .ssh and paste the two files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.

Then don't run ssh -T git@github.com
but:

```
ssh -T git@github.com -i <path-to-id_rsa>
```

and rly take care that you use  C:/.../.../ **and NOT** C:\...\...\..

This solved my problem. Maybe you have the same problem.

Comment: I had similiar issue your, my private key wasn't cached correctly on there servers,drop support an email

Comment: hi codejunkie, i update it. got it finally ;)

Comment: use pageant, ugly Git-boys, and save you asssssss!

Answer (score 3):

Another SO post contains the solution:

[Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081456/1463090)

Try to copy `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` into the Git Installation folder.
Something like this: `C:\users\user\.ssh` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

> I wasn't able to find even the folder

That folder can be any folder you want, as long as you define an `HOME` user environment variable (which isn't defined by default on Windows Xp or Seven)

If you define `HOME` to `C:\path\to\folder`, then `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` need to be stored in:

```
 C:\path\to\folder\.ssh
```