# Heroku key not accepted

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I'm trying to push to heroku but am getting a permission denied error. I've followed the articles from these locations:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

[Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end)

But those aren't working out.

Here is the output from shell to show what I'm trying to do:

```
[root]# heroku keys
  You have no keys.
[root]# heroku login
  Enter your Heroku credentials.
  Email: myemail@domain.com
  Password (typing will be hidden): 
  Found the following SSH public keys:
  1) github.pub
  2) heroku.pub
  Which would you like to use with your Heroku account? 2
  Uploading SSH public key /root/.ssh/heroku.pub... done
  Authentication successful.
[root]# git init
  Reinitialized existing Git repository in /.git/
[root]# git push heroku master
  Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Edit: This is for a CentOS server.

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Are you using a key manager like `ssh-agent`?

Comment: I am on Mac but this is on a CentOS server.

Comment: Even still, is `ssh-agent` being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.. I guess you actually need to use id_rsa instead of a custom one.. soon as I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa` it worked. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, I add another answer (following @redhotvengeance comment above) which does not require that you use id_rsa for your heroku key.
The following series of commands launches the ssh-agent and adds your heroku key so that push becomes successful:

```
ssh-agent
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_heroku_key
# now it should work
git push heroku master
```

And it's working nicely.