# Issue Pushing Code to Heroku Public Key Error

Tags: git, heroku

I am having a problem pushing the code from this tutorial: http://newsinternational.github.com/iot-assistant/ to heroku. I am at step five. When I issue the    git push heroku master    command, I get the error    Permission denied (publickey). Fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.    I already tried: [Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end) and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Answer (score 0):

Check your .ssh config for heroku. Go to the .ssh folder and open the config file

```
cd ~/.ssh
subl config
```

The 'subl' is for Sublime Text, but you can use whatever editor you wish. Look for the line "IdentityFile" and make sure it has the non public key listed:

```
IdentityFile "/Users/ircmullaney/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

not

```
IdentityFile "/Users/ircmullaney/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

That did it for me.