# heroku error - Permission denied (publickey) when trying to push an update to my application.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ssh, key-generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end)

Trying to push a project update to heroku and getting

Permission denied (publickey).

I've pushed to it previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload local keys to heroku.

Personal local keys are in `~/.ssh` or if not they can be generated with `ssh-keygen`

The answer it to do `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the application root.

Comment: if you're on windows you may need to do extra with your keys. See http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2011/05/18/heroku-trouble-with-windows-and-ssh-keys/