# Git push heroku master does nothing

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am on windows 7.

I followed the documentation on heroku there: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

when I execute

> git push heroku master

it does absolutely nothing and I get no error. I tried to re-generate my ssh key, to delete everything and do it again. Always the same.

Sorry for providing so few info but as I have no error message, it is really difficult for me to figure out...

Comment: Did everything in the tutorial up to that point work correctly? All of the output was, until then, as you expected?

Comment: run git remote and see what remotes are listed

Comment: Please attach your .git/config. For check heroku repo config.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else has this problem, my issue was that I was not pushing from my local master branch to heroku/master. You have to either push from your local master branch to heroku/master or run the command

```
git push heroku yourbranch:master
```

This is from the heroku documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late, but just wanted to add the following:

A simple login over the cli resolved the issue for me.

```
heroku login
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. SSH Key problem. So if you have no error message on window, try to re-created manually your ssh key following this instruction and it will work. [Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end/7993122#7993122)

Answer (score 0):

Comment above ^ worked for me:

```
heroku login
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
heroku logout
heroku login
```

And it worked