# How do I get my Play 2.1 app started on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I am trying to start a Play 2.1 app on Heroku but I don't know how to get it started on one dyno.  I am trying to deploy the '**demo**' app from "**SecureSocial**" to Heroku.  I used the IntelliJ-IDEA Heroku plugin to upload my project to Heroku.  I am using the suggested "**Procfile**" but I do not know how to get Heroku to start up a dyno.  It is acting like it wont start and I don't know how to resolve it.

My Procfile (in the root of my project) contains:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=
  org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL
```

Perhaps I haven't actually uploaded my code to Heroku, but I just think I have?  How can I tell?  Heroku doesn't seem to allow me to browse the code.

My IntelliJ-IDEA [Heroku plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=6659) was able to create the Heroku online project and so I see no reason why it shouldn't have pushed code to "**heroku master**" for me.   One problem I have right now is that the command line git push fails:

```
C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:signup-sheet.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:signup-sheet.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/djangofan/signup-sheet.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/djangofan/signup-sheet.git (push)

C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: djangofan@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.

C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>heroku create
Creating nameless-depths-2834... done, stack is cedar
http://nameless-depths-2834.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:nameless-depths-2834.git

C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>heroku releases
=== signup-sheet Releases
v2  Enable Logplex   djangofan@gmail.com  2013/06/12 21:37:43 (~ 10h ago)
v1  Initial release  djangofan@gmail.com  2013/06/12 21:37:42 (~ 10h ago)
```

Comment: You can tell if you have pushed your code to Heroku by looking the activity section of your dashboard for your app:  https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/activity

Comment: I have one log entry in "Activity" that says "Initial release about 11 hours ago" and one other log entry that says "enable logplex".

Comment: You can also use the command line if you have the toolbelt installed and check if you have a release using: heroku release

Comment: @JR0cket - I updated my question with that info.

Comment: It sound likes you have not pushed your code.  Or if you did, perhaps it failed as you dont have your public key added to heroku.  Either check your IntelliJ logs or if you have a command line git client (part of the Heroku Toolbelt) then you can see if there are errors by doing: git push heroku master

Comment: I'll be offline until tonight.

Comment: You either do not have a key added to heroku, or perhaps the wrong key has been added.  Using the Heroku toolbelt, on the command line use: heroku keys

Comment: If you have one or more keys listed and you dont know if any are the right ones, use: heroku keys:clear ; heroku keys:add /path/to/the/correct/key.pub

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  I think I can figure this out with that.  Would Git in Toolbelt conflict with another installation of Git on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this lines

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

it seems to be an issue with the Public key associated to your Heroku git repository. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end) has the answer you seek.

Comment: That certainly looks promising.  I will try it tonight and get back to you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can create Heroku applications with only an Heroku account, you cannot deploy any code until you have a public key added to Heroku.  You can tell if you have a key added using the Heroku toolbelt ( http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ ) and the following command:

```
heroku keys
```

If you have multiple keys listed, or do not know which key is the right one, you can clear all keys and add the key you know is correct.  If you only have one key, then you dont need to specify it.

```
heroku keys:clear
heroku keys:add /path/to/public/key/for/heroku.pub
```

If your key is called something other than id_rsa.pub then you may need to create an SSH config file to define which key should be used for Heroku

```
Host heroku.com
Hostname heroku.com
Port 22
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/heroku  # or what ever you called the public key
TCPKeepAlive yes
user name@email-address.com  # include the email address used for your heroku account
```

You should now be able to push your code to Heroku and therefore create a "Deploy" release, eg:

V6 Deploy 53u883u

Thanks

Comment: I already have this information in the Gist link I provided in my reply to Pere Villega's answer.  Thanks though.  In this case I added that file (on Windows) although I am unsure of the effect it had.  My problem, that caused this whole fiasco, was likely related to me incorrectly setting the HOME var to Git home rather than to my users home dir.