# Error while deploying application in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am getting below error while creating app and deploying in heroku using below command

**sudo git push heroku master**

**Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**
I tried all the possible scenarios
creating new ssh key , giving admin rights to folder, deleting git remote for heroku and adding it again etc
Steps followed by me:
1) git init
2) git add . 
3) git commit -m "Initial Commit"
4) heroku login
5) heroku create
6) sudo git push heroku master
Usually when we create new heroku project using "**heroku create**" it will create new project and that heroku URL is set as heroku GIT remote URL, but that also not happening everytime i am doing it manually. 
 May be this also due to that same issue i guess...
Below is my detailed error
**ponvino@ponvino-desktop:~/RubyWorkspace/prod/theScholarsPage$ sudo mv ~/.ssh/ /.ssh_backup
ponvino@ponvino-desktop:~/RubyWorkspace/prod/theScholarsPage$ heroku keys:add

Could not find an existing public key.

Would you like to generate one? [Yn] y

Generating new SSH public key.

Uploading SSH public key /home/ponvino/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done

ponvino@ponvino-desktop:~/RubyWorkspace/prod/theScholarsPage$ git push heroku master

The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.156)' can't be established.

RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.156' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.**

Please help me

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: you need to upload your public key on heroku

Comment: yes while doing **heroku login** it got automatically uploaded. I verified the uploaded key using **heroku keys** it is correct only.. Thanks

Comment: what os you on? also post the output of `heroku keys:add`

Comment: @GaurishSharma i am using Ubuntu 13.04 ..                        This is my output                                              heroku keys:add
Found the following SSH public keys:                                
1) id2_rsa.pub                                                      
2) id_dsa.pub                                                       
3) id_rsa.pub                                                       
Which would you like to use with your Heroku account? 2             
Uploading SSH public key /home/ponvino/.ssh/id_dsa.pub...done

Comment: Maybe there is no remote named "heroku". What do you see when you run `git remote -v`?

Comment: What happens if you try the last step without "sudo"?

Comment: @ponvino see my answer. it will fix your problem

Comment: @Wizard of Ogz When i try without sudo i got two more line error in addition to that **"Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of known hosts.
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key."** git remote -v is returning proper remote address..  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that your ssh key is loaded:

```
ssh-add -l
```

If not:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private_key
```

Try again to push to heroku

Comment: Yes it is already loaded . **ssh-add -l** is returning my SSH keys.  Thanks

Comment: Finally this is the right answer.. I first tried ssh-add -l it returned my keys so i didn't tried your second step but atlast it only helped me Thank you very much

Comment: you welcome. If you need more information on `ssh-add` command, look here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh-add.1.html

Answer (score 4):

You should generate pair of keys and add your public key to your heroku account.
More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and then:

```
heroku keys:add
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works even after trying the above solutions. do this

```
$ mv ~/.ssh/ ~/.ssh_backup
$ heroku keys:add
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: It is creating new SSH key and uploading it properly but again i am getting same error...   Thanks

Comment: interesting. did you run git with sudo? can you post the full output?

Comment: posted full output in main post... i even tried git with sudo but not working ... Thanks

Comment: you should never use git sudo. Further, also post the output of `git remote -v` & `heroku login`? lastly, also post the output of `heroku apps`, does it contain your app name?

Comment: Hi,

I got solution from this, Thanks for your help...After adding SSH identity it is working..

http://ripan27.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/ssh-gitgithub-com-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key-permission-denied-publickey/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Almost same problem was asked and answered in the link below.

[Try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end?rq=1)

Comment: That pblm is different see the differnce in error there **"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"** For me **"fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists"** Thanks