# How to switch between keys to push to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, public-key

At my work station at the office, I set a new key and push successfully.

But at home, I forgot my password. So I generated a new key and added it

[image: process in the command line]

I set a password that I memorized. But when I went to push to Heroku, rather than being asked for the password respective of the public key I was asked for, I was instead prompted for a password to a different key.

[image: heroku password]

I also looked at [Heroku's documentation on keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) but they did not mention how to remove the old keys.

I am also aware of the question [Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end?rq=1) but that does not explain why I am not able to switch between keys.

Yes I have created a new key and uploaded it

```
Juan-Gallardos-MacBook-Pro:.ssh juangallardo$ heroku keys:add heroku_sucks.pub
Uploading SSH public key heroku_sucks.pub... done
Juan-Gallardos-MacBook-Pro:.ssh juangallardo$
```

But stil got

```
Cloning into 'cssbuttongallery'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: `heroku help keys` will show you what you need to do to remove a key - it'll be `heroku keys:remove KEY`

Comment: @JohnBeynon, this is weird. I even cleared all my keys. Then did `heroku keys:add` then selected the key that I knew the password to. But when attempting to clone, I still got prompted to enter a key that I did not remember the password to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Heroku's documentation was incomplete I found some guidance from Github. Apparently I was not using my SSH Key https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey#make-sure-you-have-a-key-and-ssh-is-using-it . Which I found out by running

```
ssh-add -l
```

I then added it by running

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/[name_of_key]
```

So you just replace "[name_of_key]" with your filename (modify the path if you need to). And do not include the `.pub` extension or you will get an `WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!` error.

You will then be prompted for your passphrase

```
Enter passphrase
```

And get a confirmation if all goes well

```
Identity added:
```