# Pushing git repo to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

I am trying to push a django project to heroku using the command:

```
git push staging master
```

and staging refers to this git config:

```
[remote "staging"]
    url = git@heroku.com:heorku-server.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
```

But I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 128) while executing 'git push staging master'

Aborting.
```

I checked the git repo and the heroku server and they both have my exact public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't make a comment (which is what this response should be), not enough magic internet points.

You may need to generate a new set of SSH keys, but I would try what is in this thread first - [Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end)

It beats me copy-pasting the steps here right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I figured out these exact steps myself.  Adding the key worked for one day and then I ended up creating a new key.