# How to push to a heroku forked project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, terminal

I have an app: `betsmart_us` and I did a `heroku betsmart_eu --region eu` which created a new forked heroku app: `betsmart_eu`.

I can not figure a way to push changes or run rake task from my terminal to the new forked heroku app. How can I retrieve the source code of that newly created app so that I can push and test rake task from my terminal.

I tried to do a `heroku clone` but the forked app apears to be an empty repo. Yet, the forked app works fine on heroku.

Some light on this will be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Antoine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app

> Forking your application doesn’t automatically create a new git remote
>   in your current project. To deploy to targetapp you will need to
>   establish the git remote yourself. Use heroku info to retrieve the Git
>   URL of the new application and the set it manually.

Essentially, you need to add a git remote:

```
git remote add forked git@heroku.com:targetapp.git
```

Comment: Cool, thanks I understand it better now. But now when I want to do a `git push forked master` I have a **Permission denied (publickey)** which lead me to my question how to do the push ?

Comment: That's a different question from what you asked. If my answer addressed your question, please flag as answer accordingly. For you second concern, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking.  You can append --app to a command in heroku and it will point it to the correct app you are trying to run commands on.

ie

```
--app betmart_us
--app betsmart_eu
```