# github access denied access for push

Tags: git, github, git-push

Hi I'm following a beginner tutorial for [an rails app](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#sec-github). But I'm having an issue with pushing the repository. Each time I'm doing and git push -u to origin master I'm having this error.

```
guinslym@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_tuto/first_app$ git remote add origin https://github.com/guinslym/first_app.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
guinslym@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_tuto/first_app$ git push -u origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
guinslym@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_tuto/first_app$ 

guinslym@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_tuto/first_app$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27[Private information I will not post it to stackoverflow]
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/guinslym/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/guinslym/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.252.130]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Hi guinslym! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2664, received 2688 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 21363.1, received 21555.6
debug1: Exit status 1
guinslym@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_tuto/first_app$
```

Here I did setup an private key to use but I'm still having error when I want to push. I did follow this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138705/github-permission-denied-publickey) (the first answer)

```
guinslym@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
guinslym@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh -i id_rsa.pub -vT git@github.com
    ...
Hi guinslym! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
    debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
    Transferred: sent 2664, received 2688 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
    Bytes per second: sent 22659.2, received 22863.4
    debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: what does your remote look like? `git remote -v`

Comment: `guinslym@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_tuto/first_app$ git remote -v
origin ssh://github.com/guinslym/first_app.git (fetch)
origin ssh://github.com/guinslym/first_app.git (push)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to change your ssh url by an http one for your remote 'origin', use:

```
git remote set-url origin https://guinslym@github.com/guinslym/first_app.git
```

It will ask for your GitHub password on the `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is that you are sshing in to the box your trying to push from and you have agent forwarding enabled.

E.g:

```
user@box-a:~ ssh box-b
user@box-b:~ git -C path/to/repo push
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In this case it would be trying to use keys from box-a to authenticate. Solutions are:

- Add key from box-a to github
- Disable agent forwarding on box-a

To disable agent forwarding, add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *github.com
    ForwardAgent no
```