# github fails to use custom ssh-key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm having issues getting github to recognize my SSH keys that are not named `id_rsa`

For example, if I create an ssh key called `git_rsa` and then have copy `git_rsa.pub` in to my github account, then try to do a `git push` or `git pull` I run in to

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

On another machine I just used the default `id_rsa` code and it worked fine.

Comment: add your key to the ssh-agent by calling `ssh-add ~/path/to/key/git_rsa`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github: Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138705/github-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: @phd I believe that may be the problem. At least it seems to have fixed it on my current system, thank you.