# Suddenly can't commit using GIT desktop

Tags: windows, git, desktop

For some apparent reason i can't commit to a new repo which i just made.
Git for desktop says the following:

[image]

Trying the first line in cmd gives the following error...

[image]

There indeed is no folder in Roaming called 'SPB_Data', nor would i know what it is for or why git even gets pointed that way..

I've tried a lot of things already and can't find anything that seems to help.
It seems that the git installation got messed up for some reason, i think...

How do i fix this?

I'm on windows 10

Comment: have you tried to re-install git, maybe your installation failed? and for the first error its normal , git just wants you to specify your username and email to show who comited on the repository

Answer (score 1):

Some software set probably set you %HOME variable wrongly. Refer to the comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38878680/1319284). And then you probably have to set your %HOME to the correct directory, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840909/1319284) to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment :

```
have you tried to re-install git, maybe your installation failed? and for the 
first error its normal , git just wants you to specify your username and email 
to show who comited on the repository
```

To clarify the problem: your git installation normally set a %HOME% Variable but its pretty unreliable and probably the root of your problem. As shown in your error message git can't find the config files with your %HOMe% variable so you need to manually change it or re-install git.

As seen in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051282/7141618 , you can verify where your %HOME% path points to and if its the wrong directory you can change it using the windows tool like in this link: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm , to sum it up open you settings, then click on advanced system setting, open the advanced tab and there should be a environement variable button that you can click to edit them.Finally just edit the %HOME% path to fit your git installation folder